# IntelIJ ищет текстовый файл в apache tomcat вместо корня проекта

Tags: java

```
System.out.println(Paths.get("WordBase.txt").toAbsolutePath());
вывод консоли\\C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.85\bin\WordBase.txt
```

Могу корректно использовать файл только при указании абсолютного пути, можно как-то исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приведите структуру проекта, откуда вы хотите получить файл.

Comment: добавил структуру

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поместите файл в папку `src` там вы сможете использовать`getResourceAsStream()`. Или создайте папку с ресурсами мавена где можно хранить текстовые файлы.

Answer (score 0):

по хорошему файл должен быть внутри web, например, путь из сервлета к файлу будет выглядеть как getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "WordBase.txt"